# Seeking Recommendations for Automated Testing Tools for Smart TVs and HbbTV Apps

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, smart-tv, hbbtv

I am currently delving into the realm of automated testing, with a particular focus on TV applications, encompassing both Smart TVs and HbbTV (Hybrid Broadcast Broadband TV) apps.

I am reaching out to inquire if anyone here could shed light on and recommend robust tools or frameworks that are well-suited for conducting automated testing on these specific platforms. Insights into tools that have proven effective in handling the unique challenges posed by these environments would be highly valued.

If you have firsthand experience using such tools, I would greatly appreciate it if you could share your thoughts, along with any notable advantages or disadvantages you’ve encountered. Your expertise and recommendations will play a crucial role in guiding my approach to ensuring the quality and reliability of TV applications.

Thank you very much in advance for your time and assistance.